# GNU Radio - osmocom_fft issue with SDR

Tags: python, gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

After recompiling twice, tried pybomb and install from repo I can't get my SDR working using hackrf.

After experiencing some -5 and -1000 errors with the hackrf_info command, I can start grc without errors but it doesn't plot the spectrum.

By clicking on the plot seems to be a python fault of my installation.

```
     Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gnuradi/wxgui/plotter/common.py", line 122, in <lambda>
self._plotter.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, lambda evt: plotter.call_freq_callback(evt.GetPosition()))
       File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gnuradio/wxgui/plotter/grid_plotter_base.py", line 96, in call_freq_callback
if x < self.padding_left or x > self.width-self.padding_right: return
     AttributeError: 'channel_plotter' object has no attribute 'padding_left'
```

Comment: What is your linux distro?

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 and an older virtualized Ubuntu distro